# How to increase limit of project opened in same window

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I am using PhpStorm 2017, which has the option to open more than one project per window.

But It seem that the actual limit is only 4 projects.

Do you know how to increase this limit?

[image]

Resolved:

Change to diferent names is each root source folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked version 2017.1.4 - there's no such limit so far. 
Are you getting any errors while trying to attach 5th project?

Comment: Aparently you cannot use same directory root folder name in multiple projects, if you wish open all at same time. So I changed the name of root directories.